# COPY (import) data into PostgreSQL array column

Tags: arrays, postgresql, postgresql-8.4

How should a (CSV?) text file be formatted so that it can be imported (with `COPY`?) into an array column in a PostgreSQL (8.4) table?

Given table `testarray`:

```
 Column  |          Type           |
---------+-------------------------|
 rundate | date                    | 
 runtype | integer                 | 
 raw     | double precision[]      | 
 labels  | character varying(16)[] | 
 results | double precision[]      | 
 outcome | character varying(8)[]  |
```

and

```
COPY testarray from '/tmp/import.txt' CSV
```

neither of the following contents of `import.txt` work:

```
2010/06/22,88,{{1,2},{3,4}},{{1,2},{3,4}},{{1,2},{3,4}},{{1,2},{3,4}}
2010/06/22,88,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4
2010/06/22,88,'{{1,2},{3,4}}','{{1,2},{3,4}}','{{1,2},{3,4}}','{{1,2},{3,4}}'
2010/06/22,88,'1,2,3,4','1,2,3,4','1,2,3,4','1,2,3,4'
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
COPY testarray from '/tmp/import.txt' CSV

2010-06-22,88,"{{1,2},{3,4}}","{{1,2},{3,4}}","{{1,2},{3,4}}","{{1,2},{3,4}}"
```

Comment: Note that this is the *default* format, but you can choose to override the default quote character. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/sql-copy.html